# Real-Valued Symmetric Square Matrices and Min-Max

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, positive-definite

A real-valued symmetric square matrix is called positive definite if $(x,Ax)>0$ for all $x\neq0,$ where $(.,.)$ represents the scalar product. For a positive definite matrix determine

$$\max\left\{ \frac{(x,Ax)}{||x||^2};x\neq0\right\}$$

and

$$\min\left\{ \frac{(x,Ax)}{||x||^2};x\neq0\right\}.$$

Also for an infinite-dimensional vector space determine an analogue of this at which

$$\min\left\{ \frac{(x,Ax)}{||x||^2};(x,Ax)>0\right\}=0.$$

I hope this make sense and so far I have looked into Min-Max theorem, Positive definite matrices, and a few other topics but have no idea as to how I should proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, then the [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) ensures that all its [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) $\lambda_i$ are real and that there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$ made of [eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of $A$.
Then
$$
\|A\| = \sup\left\{\|Ax\|\,:~\|x\|=1\right\}
=\max_i\left|\lambda_i\right|
$$

To see this, let $\{v_1\ldots v_n\}$ be such orthonormal basis, where $v_i$ is the eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ (there might be $i\neq j$ s.t. $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$).
That is,
$$
Av_i = \lambda_iv_i
\quad\text{and}\quad
(v_i,v_j) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } i=j\\0&\text{if }i\neq j\end{cases}
$$
Any $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis $\{v_1\ldots v_n\}$: $x=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$. Then, by orthonormality,
$$
\|x\|^2 = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i\right\|^2
=
\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2
$$
and
$$
\left\|Ax\right\|^2 = \left\|A\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i\right\|^2
=
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^nc_iAv_i\right\|^2
=
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\lambda_iv_i\right\|^2
=
\sum_{i=1}^n\|c_i\lambda_iv_i\|^2
=
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2\lambda_i^2
$$
You can easily see that among all the $x\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|=1$, one that maximizes $\|Ax\|$ is $v_j$ where $|\lambda_j|$ is the largest eigenvalue in absolute value.

If $A$ is positive definite then all the eigenvalues are positive, as you can easily verify by computing $(v_i,Av_i)$ for all $i$.

---

As to the infinite dimensional case, take $\{e_n\}$ to be an orthonormal basis of the space $\mathcal H$, and define
$$
T:\mathcal H\rightarrow\mathcal H \quad\text{s.t.}\quad Te_n = \tfrac1ne_n ~\text{ on the basis}
$$
$T$ is positive definite with eigenvalues $\{\frac1n\}_{n\in\mathbb N^+}$, but the infimum of such set is $0$.